# SSIS C# Script Error reading Windows Registry Key

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a huge problem and I don't even know what to check.
   I have a big SSIS package which at beginning it runs an "Execute Script" task (named ST_2275f0b3eced4c84bd35d4c826cab866.csproj), wrote in C#, which looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ST_2275f0b3eced4c84bd35d4c826cab866.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
public void Main()
        {

            Dts.Variables["user_uca"].Value = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\TDCredentials").GetValue("user_uca").ToString();

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Bottom line is that it loads a SSIS package variable with the data from a specific Windows Registry key.
The issue is that when I ran the SSIS package from Visual Studio it works. But when I ran the Sql Agent Job which was made for that SSIS package, it gives me the error:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at ST_2275f0b3eced4c84bd35d4c826cab866.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
This error means that the Windows Registry key does not exists. Because if I deleted on purpose the specific Windows Registry key and then ran the SSIS package from Visual Studio, I get the exact error message.
I have checked all that I could thing of: the sql server and the host having those Windows Registry key - they are the same. Also i gave permissions for "Everyone" for those keys, also I had put the key in HKLocalMachine, in order to be sure they exist for all the users, still same error.
Any hints?!
Thanks in advance, Bogdan.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ultimately a permissions issue. Either that the service account that runs SQL Agent or the Credentials you are running the subsystem jobs step of SSIS does not have the ability to read that part of the registry.

You need to either grant that user access or create a delegate that *can* read from the registry.

As a side note, you don't have to use your Script approach. Reading Registry values and assigning them to Variables is native functionality in SSIS. See [Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for more information on the topic. You will still have to deal with the permission issue but then you won't have code copy and pasted throughout your packages.

Answer (score 0):

As said, it was a permission issue for the account which was running the sql agent job.
    Therefore the solution was first to make a new credential, from "Credentials" -> "New Credential". In the "Identity" field I choose an user with sysadmin rights (eg. john.doe). In the field "Credential name" I had filled "John". Then from Sql Server Agent -> Proxies -> SSIS Package Execution I created "New Proxy". I filled at "Proxy name" a name (ProxyJohn), at "Credential name" I choose the credential defined early, "John", then at field "Active to the following subsystems" I have checked the "Sql Server Integration Services Package" option.
    Then, at my Sql Server Agent -> Jobs, on my job (which gave me the error message when ran), in proprieties -> Steps-> "Run As" I have choose the new credential created above, named "ProxyJohn" instead of "Sql Server Agent Service Account" (which was by default)
    It worked like a charm.

Hope it will help. 
Best regards, Bogdan